# Explanation of number shifts in the Tanach

Tags: sources-mekorot, tanach, number, grammar-dikduk

In many places in Tanach, the grammatical number (plural or singular) shifts. One famous example has to do with the rocks that Yaakov put under his head. When he woke, the "rock" is referred to in the singular and the [medrash](https://outorah.org/p/22387/) establishes an explanation for the switch.

This switch also occurs in a variety of situations as it applies to the nation of Israel. Sometimes the people is spoken to or about as a singular (as evidenced by the pronoun and verbs) and sometimes as a plural. This switch even happens mid verse in some cases.

I know that some of the switches are functions of grammar (the the Sh'ma verse, Moshe speaks to the people as a singular so the verb is "sh'ma" and not "shim'u", but then includes himself at the end of the posuk saying Hashem is OUR God) and some, I have heard reflect a more homiletic approach (one people with one heart explains the singular while division or a lack of spiritual focus points to the plural).

Is there any comprehensive treatment of the shift between singular and plural through Tanach as it relates to the nation, explaining the reason for the switch (through reference to grammar, logic or medrash)?

Comment: I remember this one: https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0214.htm#10 Shouldn't we start a wiki to see how far we can get?

Comment: Since each case would involve a separate explanation, you would need to analye each case.

Comment: @sabbahillel maybe, or maybe they could be categorized and explained. So one that is a function of grammar can be labelled "grammar' and then explained. I also assume that many would like an "am echad, lev echad" thinking so the list would just need a commentator's name with that tag.

Comment: It would be hard to believe that no one ever wrote a book on the subject or at least some Bible Studies doctorate or something. Will see if I can find anything.

Comment: @Harel13 thanks -- I was considering assigning it as a project if it didn't already exist.

Comment: Hey, I just saw this on Quora yesterday!

Comment: @MichaBerger I didn't post it there -- can you give a link so I can see if there are any answers there?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-explanation-for-the-number-shifts-in-the-tanach-sources-mekorot-tanach-number-grammar-dikduk-Judaism

Literally the same words, posted on the same day (Aug 23):
"What is an explanation for the number shifts in the tanach (sources mekorot, tanach, number, grammar dikduk, Judaism)?"

Tags: Hebrew Bible, Torah, Number Systems, Judaism, Numbers (mathematics)

Comment: @MichaBerger Thanks -- weird coincidence.

Comment: I agree with @sabbahillel that the rule "דברה התורה כלשון בני אדם" applies here, and the shifts are to be explained on a case by case basis

Comment: @AlBerko I understand -- I'm looking for a compendium of the explanations on that case-by-case basis.

Comment: Because you wrote "comprehensive treatment of the *shift*" in the single, it sounds as you expect one explanation for all.

Comment: I don't remember specific places, but doesn't Rashi many times give an explanation for why this apparent grammatical inconsistency appears in a given sentence?